# Calculating and looping summaries for individual participants into a table

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, summary

I have data from several hundred participants who each provided between 1 and 6 sentences. They then rated their sentence(s) on 4 dimensions, as did two external raters.

I'd like to create a table, grouped by participant, with columns showing these values:

- Participants' rate of agreement with rater 1 (`par1`), with rater 2 (`par2`) and overall (`paro`)
- Participants' rate of agreement for each dimension with rater 1 (`pad1.1`, `pad2.1` etc.), with rater 2 (`pad1.2`, `pad2.2` etc.) and overall (`pad1.o`, `pad2.o` etc.)
- Mean difference in rating between participant and rater 1 (`mdrp1`), rater 2 (`mdrp2`) and both raters (`mdrpo`)
- Mean difference in rating for each dimension between participant and rater 1 (`mdr1p1`, `mdr2p1` etc.), rater 2 (`mdr1p2`, `mdr2p2` etc.) and both raters (`mdr1po`, `mdr2po` etc.)

(So with 4 dimensions there should be 30 values per participant)

Due to the size and structure of the data, I'm not sure where to start on this. I'm guessing that a loop would be necessary, but I've struggled to get my head around how to do that as well.

For agreement I'm considering adding TRUE/FALSE variables and then replacing them with 1 and 0 to eventually calculate agreement:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(par1 = (df$d1 == df$r1.1)
df <- df %>% mutate(par2 = (df$d1 == df$r2.1)
df <- df %>% mutate(paro = (df$d1 == df$r1.1 & df$d1 == df$r2.1)
```

And similarly for mean differences, adding variables with rating difference for each dimension...

```
df <- df %>% mutate(mdr1p1 = (df$d1 - df$r1.1))
df <- df %>% mutate(mdr1p2 = (df$d1 - df$r2.1))
df <- df %>% mutate(mdr1po = (df$d1 - ((df$r1.1 + df$r2.1)/2)))
```

...But these seem to be quite inefficient approaches!

My data looks like this:

```
    ID   Ans   d1   d2   d3   d4   r1.1  r1.2  r1.3  r1.4  r2.1  r2.2  r2.3  r2.4
1   53   abc   3    3    3    3    3     2     4     3     3     2     4     3
2   a4   def   3    3    3    3    3     1     2     3     3     1     3     3
3   a4   ghi   4    4    4    4    3     2     5     1     3     1     5     2
4   hj   jkl   3    3    3    3    3     1     3     3     3     1     5     3
5   32   mno   2    3    3    3    3     1     3     2     3     1     3     3
6   32   pqr   3    3    3    2    3     2     5     3     4     2     3     3
```

`ID` = participant

`Ans` = participants' written answer

`d` = dimension rated by participant

`r1` = dimensions rated by external rater 1

`r2` = dimensions rated by external rater 2

**Example data:**

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), 
Ans = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu"), 
d1 = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), d2 = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), 
d3 = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), d4 = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), 
r1.1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), r1.2 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
r1.3 = c(4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L), r1.4 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), 
r2.1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), r2.2 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
r2.3 = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L), r2.4 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L)), 
row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'd suggest reorganizing your data to long format, where each row corresponds to an ID and question (perhaps using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. Then use dplyr (eg `group_by()`) to group by ID and calculate summary metrics. I can demonstrate if you like.